# Debugging AngularJS Code in JHipster (Intellij)

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, jhipster

I am running Application.java from within IntelliJ and Grunt Serve from the Command Window. Thus, I can debug Java code and Live Reload changes to Html. But I cannot set breakpoints or trace Javascript files.

I know I could debug in Chrome, but I rather debug in IntelliJ if at all possible.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the [NodeJS](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-and-debugging-node-js.html) plugin for IntelliJ. I have it installed on my machine and I'm able to right-click on my project's Gruntfile.js and select Run or Debug.

Comment: I had to run debug for the index.html in order to get LiveEdit. By default this tried to read the file locally, so I changed the url of the browser running the IntelliJ plugin to the one assigned by Gruntfile serve. Thanks Matt